# Can't decide what message to print after catching an exception

Tags: c++

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

class excp1:exception
{
    public:
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "Bad ass exception";
    }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try
    {
        if(1!=0)
            throw new excp1();
    }
    catch(excp1& e)
    {
        cerr<<e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't print what I have put as return value of what ("Bad ass exception"), instead it prints:

```
Terminate called after throwing an instance of' excp1*'
Aborted
```

How to manage to print what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should throw the exception by value and catch it by reference.

You should have:

```
throw excp1();
```

Throwing a pointer type with dynamic memory allocation would leak the memory and cause **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Shouldn't it be catch by *`const`* reference here too?

Comment: @awoodland: Preferably, Yes, Here OP doesn't modify the state of the exception object in the catch handler.Typically, so will be the case.So Yes that can be generalized to some extent as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having a type problem:

You're throwing a `excp*` and catching a `excp`.

Try changing it to:

```
throw excp1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the "new".  Your catch isn't catching a pointer, it's catching a reference, so it is looking at the pointer and saying "Me? No way."